# How to send state from Child component to another component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with sending state from Child to Parent.
After clicking on Menu in Main component I want to change state active and send this active to Sidebar component, because I want to hide/show Sidebar depends on active class from css. It is easy in Vanilla JS but in React I am little confused.

Main:

```
import Menu from "./Menu";

import "./Styles.css";

import teamsdb from "./teamsdb";

const Main = ({ name }) => {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Menu />
      <h1>Main</h1>
      <h4>{teamName}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Menu:

```
const Menu = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const changeMenu = () => {
    setActive(!active);
  };
  return <button onClick={changeMenu}>Menu</button>;
};

export default Menu;
```

Sidebar:

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
  const handleChange = e => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
    console.log("Search: ", e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className={active ? 'sidebar active' : 'sidebar'}>
      <div className="sidebar__header">
        Header
        <button>Colors</button>
      </div>
      <div className="sidebar__search">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <Teams search={searchTerm} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import Main from "./components/Main";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";    
function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <div className="app__body">
            <Router>
              <Sidebar />
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/team/:teamId">
                  <Main />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/">
                  <Main />
                </Route>
              </Switch>
            </Router>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Where do you use `<Sidebar />` component?

Comment: In main file App.js.

Comment: Can you please share that file as well? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I add App.js to question

Comment: you can store the `active` state in `App` component and pass it as props to `Sidebar`

Comment: Whenever you wish to pass the state from a child component to the parent component, you should lift the state up to the parent component. You'll have to maintain the state in the parent component itself and also add the event handlers to change state right in the parent component. And you can then pass in this state as props to the child component. This way, it gets to keep the state and your parent component also has access to the state.

Comment: Decide whether you want to use arrow functions or function declarations for function components and stick to it. Mixing them doesn't look good (lack of consistency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should lift your state up the first common ancestor component, in your case: App. This way you can use it in all its descendants by passing the state and the mutation function (setActive) as prop:

```
      App    // Put active state here, pass down active and setActive as prop
       ^
       |
  +----+-----+
  |          |
  +          +
Sidebar     Main  // Pass down active and setActive as prop
             ^
             |
             |
            Menu  // Use setActive to modify state in App
```

This is explained in React documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Thank You man I didn't know that I can set setActivate as prop :) But now is working very well :)

Answer (score 0):

With the context api and hooks prop drilling isn’t required anymore. You can simply wrap the parent and child in a context provider and leverage react’s useContext hook for managing state across the 2 components. kent c dodds has a good article with examples [here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively)

Comment: Interesting read, Context API indeed offers an alternative to prop drilling, however it requires more boilerplate. So how do you choose between prop drilling and Context in practice? Do yo use hard rules, such as: no drilling more than 2 levels, or to more than 3 components?

Comment: it really just depends on the complexity of the state of the application. in bigger projects I find it preferable to utilize multiple contexts to group components that are dependent on the state that each context holds (almost like a bounded context in domain driven design). As far as hard rules its really up to the engineer who is working on the project, i normally stick to anything > 3 levels down or state that is ingested by more than 3 components I tend to use context.

Comment: Thank you, it's valuable to get this sort of practical info on React design! Would you have good material on domain driven design with React?

Comment: Its not really specific to React but I highly recommend the book Domain Driven Design Distilled by Vaughn Vernon if you’re interested in DDD.